# cannot find fragment from viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

there is a fragment in my activity in which there is a viewpager which has 5 fragments in it and inside the main activity i need to get one of the fragment from viewpager

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public void setFragment(){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    mainFragment= new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mainFragment,"mainFragment");

    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }
    }, 250);
  }

    public void findFragment() {

    mainFragment= (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mainFragment");

    viewPager = mainFragment.viewPager;
    FragmentOne fragment = (FragmentOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());


  }

}
```

MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{


private void initViewPagerAndTabs() {

    viewPager =  view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    pagerAdapter.addFragment(FragmentOne.newInstance(), "one");
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(FragmentTwo.newInstance(), "two");
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(FragmentThree.newInstance(), "three");
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(FragmentFour.newInstance(), "four");
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(FragmentFive.newInstance(), "five");

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
  }

    private static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    private PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

  }


}
```

if i use "getFragmentManager()" instead of "getChildFragmentManager()" then it returns the fragment but when i use "getChildFragmentManager()" in viewPager it returns null in activity

Comment: so above code is working? and `FragmentOne fragment = (FragmentOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());`
 is retrunging fragment?

Comment: Yes it was working but now i decided to add some more features and while doing that I'd to change getFragmentManager to getChildFragmentManager and now it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Try this Running Code for 1 fragment, may it helps you in your code :

> Main Activity

```
public class OpenQuran extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

TabLayout tabLayoutqaue;
Pager mAdapter;
MediaPlayer mp;

//This is our viewPagerss
ViewPager viewPager;
View mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_quran);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Read Quran");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayoutqaue = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutqaue);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    mAdapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // 1 Fragment
    mAdapter .addFrag(new Quran(), "Quran");


    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    tabLayoutqaue.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    tabLayoutqaue.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
```

> Fargment Class :

```
public class parahlist extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_parahlist, container, false);}


public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

}
```

> View Pager Class:

```
public class Pager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

//integer to count number of tabs
int tabCount;
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructor to the class
public Pager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    //Initializing tab count
    this.tabCount= tabCount;
}

//Overriding method getItem
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return mFragmentList.get(position);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFrag(Fragment Fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(Fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}



@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

}
```

Now This the code Of MainActivity, 2nd Fragment and 3rd one is View Pager class. You dont need to change or edit your View Pager Class. Just Create Java Class and Paste that code as it is. 
In Main Activity the Line : `mAdapter .addFrag(new Quran(), "Quran");` adding description and Fragment. You can add your own fragment after "new". 
After that you have to put Tablayout widget in you Xml as Follows:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutqaue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorgreen"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorback"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And View Pager like:

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

You may face some issue regarding tablayout :
Just put this line in your gradle build under dependecies:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

According to your version. for example you have `25.0.1`
then line will be :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1
```

Still i m here to tell you more. if you got problem!

Comment: appreciate your help but i want to know the solution to my problem and not changing a whole lot code :)